# HTML 5 Layout when using percent instead of pixels

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which works perfectly when i use pixel based measurements , but i want to use percentages instead and when i use percentage it spoils my layout like the picture attached below

[image]

As you can see the image above, the body content and site tagline are overlapping each other. I need the tagline to go within the blue section along with the unordered list below. It was working fine with the pixel based layout, its messed up now on applying percentages.

Here is my HTML 5 based markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <link href = "site.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <title>Test Page - Test Title of my homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id = "SiteTitle">
            <h1>This is a test !</h1>
        </div>
        <div id = "Tagline">
            <p>This is a test tagline of the website</p>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div id = "MainMenu">
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div id = "MainContent">
            Main Site Cotent
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        The Footer
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS file

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}
header{
background-color: blue;
height: 15%;
}
nav{

}
#SiteTitle{
color: black;
}
#Tagline{
    color: black;
}
#MainMenu ul li{
color: black;
}
#MainContent{
height: 70%;
}
footer{
background-color: green;
height: 15%;
}
```

Comment: `* { height: 100% }` makes EVERY element 100% height, I don't think that's desirable. That won't fix your problem tho. It isn't completely clear to me what you would like to achieve. Can you sketch some thing to clarify your goal.

Comment: You want 70% and 15% of the view port height?

Comment: is this working http://jsfiddle.net/4Ze6A/ added clear both property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mate,

Height property with % (percentage) value does not work as pixel values. Height percentages will be calculated based on parent elements height. Initially body does not have height as entire viewport.

The very first rule you need is:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Remember, html and body selector has to be together in order to make body height equal to vievwport height.

Now if you want to split down the viewprot height for header, section and footer - the very first thing is these elements has to be direct children of body. Then only percentage unit will work on height property.

**So your structure would be:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test Page - Test Title of my homepage</title>
    <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        header
    </header>
    <section>
        section
    </section>
    <footer>
        footer
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**And CSS for layout:**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
}

header{
    background-color: blue;
    height:25%;
}

section{
    height:65%;
}

footer{
    background-color: green;
    height:10%;
}
```

And you have a happy flexible height layout.

This wont solve your issue as very low height screen would cause overlap issues. You can fix it by applying min-height to body or desired header/section/footer elements.

**For example:**

```
header {
    min-height:80px;
}
```

**Few extra advise:**

- Dont use global selector - i.e. *
- Instead use [Normalise CSS](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)
- Percentage based height layout are not best practices.

A simple Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/9FBxd/

Comment: Thank You So Much, this just worked absolutely fine, and thanks for that extra piece of advise too! Much Appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

You need to make them inline as a block:

```
#SiteTitle, #Tagline, header nav{
   display inline-block;
}
```

This way they will be placed nexto eachother :) Might want to use `vertical-align: top;` to make them all align to the top, which you probably want.

Also, as stated in all other replies, dont use `*{height: 100%;}`, that will mess up a WHOLE lot more than it fixes (see your current problem for one).

The same goes for the margin and padding attribute. Some elements have a default padding/margin which you don't want to remove (think of the little space between two paragraphs). I asume want the body to be all trimmed, just use `html,body{margin:0;padding:0;}` for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `*{ height:100%;` makes all elements 100%. Rather use 100% for `<body>`.

This makes the body 100% height and the rest of the elements can now use percentage based measurements.

Comment: Thanks for contributing !

Answer (score 0):

just change your *CSS* to:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Remove `height:100%`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height:100%` from

```
*{

margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

add

```
body{height:100%;width:100%}
```

Here's a fiddle

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4S3r7/1/)